# Passing variables into ReportQueryBuilder - GoogleAdsAPI

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I am using [GoogleAdsApi](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/9bfa25c1bbd45957a8d670c7d744523c8457dd32/examples/adwords/v201809/reporting/download_criteria_report_with_awql.py) - and I have the query below that works great. :)

```
report_query = (adwords.ReportQueryBuilder()
                  .Select(
                    'Date','AdGroupId','AdGroupName','CampaignId','CampaignName',           
                          'Impressions','Clicks',
                          'Cost'
                          ,'Conversions','ConversionRate','Ctr','AverageCpc','CostPerConversion'
                          ) 
                  .From('CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT')
                  .Where('Status').In('ENABLED', 
                  'PAUSED')
                  .During('20200101,20210331')
                  .Build())
```

I would like to make this function more dynamic by creating a date variable (I have listed below) and possibly more variables let's say field as well. When I try to create & pass in variables ,it does not work

```
fields = "'Date','AdGroupId','AdGroupName','CampaignId','CampaignName','Impressions','Clicks','Cost','Conversions','ConversionRate','Ctr','AverageCpc','CostPerConversion'"



today = date.today()
yesterday = today - timedelta(days = 1)
date_filter = f'\'{yesterday.strftime("%Y%m%d")},{today.strftime("%Y%m%d")}\''

 report_query = (adwords.ReportQueryBuilder()
                      .Select(
                       fields
                              ) 
                      .From('CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT')
                      .Where('Status').In('ENABLED', 
                      'PAUSED')
                      .During(date_filter)
                      .Build())
```

I get the error below:

```
googleads.errors.AdWordsReportBadRequestError: Type: QueryError.INVALID_DURING_CLAUSE
```

Even though when I pass in the printed value of my date variable, instead of the date variable into .During, it works. So a little confused.

Comment: Do you need the single quotes in the string (`\'`)?

Comment: yes I need it as it needs to be passed in as a string